# Specific GA4 Events Not Appearing in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

We are monitoring leads from a website with GA4, there are two custom events respectively "Lead" (when the user fills out a form) and "WhatApp" (when the user clicks on the application's floating button). Although tracking these events is working normally in GA4, I can't find these events in BigQuery... Does anyone know what could be happening?

I don't master the bigquery SQL language, so I've been exporting the tables to Google Sheets and trying to find these events manually. I would hope to find these items so that I can refine my analyzes and optimize campaigns.

Comment: SQL is easy to learn I think. I can recommend this SQL course: https://sqlbolt.com No sign-up, free, interactive, very compact - just start learning and in 1 or 2 hours you should know the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is important to ensure that you have correctly linked GA4 to BigQuery. Once you have done that, you can check the number of event occurrences using simple SQL. It is possible that your issue may be occurring because you have exported only a small portion of the data. To remedy this, you can try using the following query instead:

> SELECT   event_date,   event_name,   COUNT(*) AS event_count FROM
> `project.dataset.events_*` WHERE event_name IN ('Lead', 'WhatsApp')
> GROUP BY event_date, event_name